# Knowledge Graph?

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, inference

I am told   "Watson also has a Proprietary Knowledge Graph trained on billions of web pages, understanding millions of “types” in text." Where can I access this Knowledge Graph? I would want to query it. I want to add to it. I want to see what inference it makes on information I add.

Answer (score 1):

As written in your question, it is a Proprietary knowledge graph. If I were IBM, I would like it to be stored very privately and unaccessible. This knowledge graph is a main asset of Watson, and therefore opening it to public would result in companies using this graph without buying Watson.

This knowledge graph is probably using some [semantic web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725261/what-is-the-semantic-web) (or similar) technologies to build ontologies and vocabularies representing some fields like oncology, medicine, etc. You may be interested in [DBPedia project](http://dbpedia.org/). It basically is a knowledge graph built from wikipedia data. It is open and can be [queried](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) thanks to [SPARQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).

To understand better semantic web principles and inferences you can do with it, you should start to learn more about RDF, RDFS, OWL.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Watson's knowledge graph is not open sourced but [YAGO](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/) (multilingual knowledge base from Wikipedia, Wordnet, and Geonames) is, which was part of the IBM Watson system that defeated Jeopardy champions.
Visit YAGO's GitHub [page](https://github.com/yago-naga/yago3) for more information regarding how to use it and querying the knowledge base.

[DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org),[WikiData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikidata) and [Freebase](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) are good alternatives of YAGO

If you are interested to know more about knowledge graph or like to build your own then refer to the SO thread [How to build a knowledge graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461062/how-to-build-a-knowledge-graph).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, Watson's Jeopardy showcase wasn't just about YAGO it was a combination of YAGO and DBpedia.

I respond as a collaborator who made this data available to the IBM Watson project at the time.

Some reference links, for additional context.

- https://magoosh.com/data-science/how-did-ibm-watson-ai-really-win-jeapordy/
- https://thebestschools.org/magazine/watson-computer-plays-jeopardy/